# Fluentvalidation with Custom Indexed Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, fluentvalidation, defaultmodelbinder

Recently I've been working on a decently complex UI in which I've had to adjust the default collection binding to use a 1 based collection instead of 0 based which ends up with inputs like the following when using Html.InputFor():

```
 <input name="Model.Collection[1].Options.SomeOption" id="Model_Collection_1__Options_SomeOption" />
 <input name="Model.Collection[2].Options.SomeOption" id="Model_Collection_2__Options_SomeOption" />
```

Initially this does not work with way MVC's model binder works by default, but I came across this post by Phil Haack detailing how to use whatever you want for the model binder to bind to for the collection.http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/
This made what I'm doing in the UI trivial, but now when I try to validate using fluent validation the name that fluent validation returns with the (correct) error message is index - 1. For instance, if in the above example Option1 is required and I leave it blank, fluent validation returns the name:

```
 Model.Collection[0].Options.SomeOption
```

I am validating my collection using the following fluent validation code:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Collection).SetCollectionValidator(new OptionValidator());
```

What I'm wondering is if I'm screwed and have to rewrite the UI or if there's some way I can force the name fluentvalidation gives me to match the name in the UI.
I'm using fluentvalidation version 6.4

PS I've been looking at this frustrated for a while, so if the question isn't super clear or more information is needed forgive me, I can edit the question for more context if needed.

Comment: After looking at this with a couple leads, I ended up just reworking the view to avoid the Fluent Validation issue.

Comment: I'm currently working through a similar issue. Would you be able to add your answer here or explain what you did? Thanks.